# How should an array of objects from an API be ordered when sorted by timestamp?

Tags: arrays, json, sorting

This is probably a trivial question, but I am genuinely curious of what people think.

I'm working on making a API that responds with a JSON array of messages that have a timestamp. These messages are sorted following the timestamp attribute in them, but I was wondering if it should be sorted ascending (old-to-new) or descending (new-to-old)?

For the sake of the question, these messages are chat messages. What I figure, is that if that's the case, it should be ascending because when a client receives the response and loops through the array to add each message to add it to their main chat list, it would be in the right order.

A sample response would look like this:

```
messages: [
  {
    "name":"John",
    "message":"Not bad",
    "timestamp":1235
  },
  {
    "name":"Bob",
    "message":"Hey, John. How are you?",
    "timestamp":1234
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a concrete 'right' answer to your question but in my opinion it should be in descending (new to old) order.

My reasoning for this is that in a chat application a very large quantity of messages have the potential to be sent and stored over the lifetime of the app. It most likely won't be practical to display all messages that have ever been sent. It will however be useful to display the most recent messages that have been sent. If the data is sent is ordered from newest to oldest, it will be easiest to retrieve the newest messages and subsequently display them.

If the messages were ordered in ascending (old to new) order, you would have to navigate to the back of the array of messages before you could access the more relevant newer messages.

Sorry if that was a little unclear. I can elaborate again if I need to.

Comment: Quite clear!

However, the way I imagined it, is that if you have it in ascending, the oldest message can be easily appended to the end of your main list. If this was a user app that responded to changes in the main-list, it would easily slide in the new messages with the oldest first until it reached the last.

Comment: To clarify further, if it were descending, you would have to reverse the list, and then append it it, which would be O(n) naturally.

Answer (score 0):

Using a library will help you. Check [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/), you can use its functions to sort your JSON variables.

Comment: Your answer makes no sense at all. I asked what would be the best way to order, NOT how should I sort it - two different things.

Comment: Take it easy it was just a suggestion okay :) What I understood is that you want to order the array by timestamp, right? So you'll sort timestamp by newest (max). http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to sound rude! My question is which way is best, ascending or descending, not how to do I sort it. Also, please let me know what part was unclear.

Comment: Oh, I thought it was a programming question. Well, logically you'll get them by most recent to the latest. Good luck then.